# Most faithful Dracula book adaptation (motion film /animation)

Tags: book-adaptation, dracula

I recently reread the book Dracula by Bram Stoker and I am searching for a movie that resembles the book closest. The 1992 film Dracula seems to have gotten only decent reviews and the love story kills it for me.

What is the most faithful adaptation of the book?

PS- I don't mind watching a movie in a language other than english if it has subtitles.

Comment: maybe asking for an adaptation that resembles the book the closest?  Relatively objective as it either resembles on a majority or not.  Saying 'better' implies subjective quality while faithfulness can be construed as an objective measurement of narrative

Comment: I think @TylerShads has it right in that the best way this question can be reworded is to make it about the most honorable film representation, but that may be up for debate. An argument explaining why one adaptation is better than the other would work though, methinks.

Comment: See also: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17376/which-dracula-movie-is-most-faithful-to-the-original-bram-stoker-book

Comment: Definitely *Coppola*'s 90s version. The atmosphere and look is amazing and still the best adaption I know regarding the actual story (even if the supposed love story in order to provide a differentiated view on *Dracula*'s character wouldn't have been neccessary). The oh so famous *Christopher Lee* flick is just ridiculous. Otherwise I second my pre-commenter's meta comments (though I'd really like to see this turn into an appropriate question).

Comment: Copola's version has differences with the original novel and hence it can not be called - 'The most faithful adaptation' which the OP is looking for. Wikipedia says "Coppola's story includes a backstory telling how Dracula (who is the historical Vlad Ţepeş in this version) became a vampire, as well as a subplot not in Stoker's original novel in which Mina Harker was revealed to be the reincarnation of Dracula's greatest love. Dracula serves as a tragic hero instead of being a villain.
"

Comment: @ChristianRau if you believe Capola's movie is the answer, please add it below.  I'd like to clean up the discussion here but feel that it might be appropriate on an answer.

Comment: @DForck42 I'm not sure my argumentation is really sufficient as an answer. And I didn't want to answer until the validity of the question is decided, anyway. But maybe I'll get to "objectifying" my opinionated comment and turn it into something valid. Feel free to delete it for now (another option might be to only delete the chatter-like and meta comments, like my discussion with *Ankit* or the first couple of comments, but I'm not in the position to decide over the validity of a comment).

Comment: @christianrau i've cleaned up the discussiony ones.  honestly i think the Capola one is a good answer, and would be made better if you argue both sides in your answer.

Answer (score 10):

[Count Dracula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Dracula_%281977%29) A TV movie made by BBC in 1977 is one of the adaptations which can be called more faithful adaptation of the book. Wikipedia says - "1977 saw a solid BBC version titled Count Dracula. It was made for television and starred Louis Jourdan as the Count and Frank Finlay as Van Helsing. It was directed by Philip Saville. This version is one of the more faithful adaptations of the book. It includes all of the main characters (only blending together Arthur and Quincey) and has scenes of Jonathan recording events in his diary and Dr. Seward speaking into his dictaphone."

Answer (score -2):

I think Coppola’s 1992 version is the closest aside from the Mina/Dracula love story and old Drac having a baboon’s butt on his head. It has none of the most common changes, like Jonathan dying or Dracula not de-aging from and older to a younger man. So stick with that one. All the other ones are bad, except for 1970’s *Count Dracula* and *Dracula* (1931). Now, BBC’s Count Dracula is very close to the book, but not the CLOSEST. Mina and Lucy are sisters, Arthur and Quincey are blended into one character called Quincey Holmwood, and Van Helsing kills Dracula, not Quincey and Jonathan. I’m also pretty sure Quincey doesn’t die like in the book, if I can remember right. He doesn’t, right? I saw Quincey by the tree sitting and I’m sure I saw his head moving a bit. Also Dracula in the bbc version seems to be bored with eternal life and blood sucking. The character is supposed to be more prone to emotion such as anger or sadness.

Comment: I disagree about Coppola's version, but your mention of the BBC version is a good find.

Comment: @ChicotheFriendlyMonkey I'm unsure whether it's supposed to be an answer in its own right, or a response to Ankit's answer, which is also about the BBC version (or *a* BBC version; they did another last year).

Comment: It’s an answer in its own right lol

Comment: Also I thought it was this year but I was talking about the Louis Jordan one